# Process of executing calls from a recursion stack, how are the calls processed, what do they return and how does that matter?

Tags: recursion, stack, binary-search-tree, sortedlist

I have heard that recursion calls take place from a stack. But the toughest thing, I find is how are they processed from the recursion stack? I have heard that the calls get stored sequentially inside a stack, the last call returns something to its previous call in the stack and the process continues. I could comprehend that while computing factorial of a number. But got stuck with the following code of converting a sorted array to a binary search tree.

Following is the code :

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, d):
        self.data = d
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
  
# function to convert sorted array to a
# balanced BST
# input : sorted array of integers
# output: root node of balanced BST
def sortedArrayToBST(arr):
      
    if not arr:
        return None
  
    # find middle
    mid = (len(arr)) / 2
      
    # make the middle element the root
    root = Node(arr[mid])
      
    # left subtree of root has all
    # values <arr[mid]
    root.left = sortedArrayToBST(arr[:mid])
      
    # right subtree of root has all 
    # values >arr[mid]
    root.right = sortedArrayToBST(arr[mid+1:])
    return root
```

Now my example set is : [-10,-3,0,5,9]

I understand that this has to be recursive because of the same process taking place multiple times. But what baffles me is what's happening inside the stack? When the control encounters a leaf node and adds it as the left child(`root.left = sortedArrayToBST(arr[:mid])`), how does the call pop out from the stack or even return something to its immediate next such that the process continues smoothly?

Can anyone please illustrate using a stack and showing the push and pop tasks happening with every call? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's probably important to note that this is not the most efficient way to implement the function because you're copying parts of the list when you do slicing. The optimal method would involve avoiding copying any part of the list by passing indices as parameters (ie `sortedArrayToBSTIndices(arr, start, end)` should be equivalent to `sortedArrayToBST(arr[start : end])`.

Comment: Try using CodeSkulptor Viz Mode http://viz.codeskulptor.org/ which walks through the execution of Python 2 code step by step.

Comment: Thank you for the information @Mark Saving. However, how do I run the code and point out the differences in it using CodeSkulptor? I pasted the code there but once I ran it, I couldn't find the breakpoints or even the line-by-line execution process. Please assist.